# How can I compute whether a sequence is an even or odd permutation of an increasing sequence?

Tags: matlab, combinatorics

> *Variants of this question have been crossposted to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351039/is-there-a-built-in-function-in-matlab-to-determine-if-a-permutation-is-even-or) and [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379809/is-there-a-name-for-this-function-parity-of-a-finite-sequence). Additional answers may be found at these other sites.*

Computational Science People:

I originally posed this as part of a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379809/is-there-a-name-for-this-function-parity-of-a-finite-sequence . The title pretty much says it all.  Given a finite sequence of real numbers which I know are distinct, I want an easy way to compute whether it is an even permutation of an increasing sequence or an odd permutation of an increasing sequence.  For example, $(5, 1.3, 8, 6, 10.5)$ is an even permutation of the increasing sequence $(1.3, 5, 6, 8, 10)$, so the answer is "even".  $(2, 3, 5, 1)$ is an odd permutation of the increasing sequence $(1, 2, 3, 5)$, so the answer is "odd".  I can get Matlab to give me a permutation *vector*, which for my first example would be $[2\ 1\ 4\ 3\ 5]$, but I cannot find a built-in function in Matlab to compute the sign of that permutation vector.  If I could get Matlab to give me the permutation *matrix*, I could take the determinant of that matrix.  People have posted quite long Matlab files on the Web to accomplish this, but I'm hoping I can avoid that.  I would also be willing to use Maple.

Please no nitpicking or unconstructive comments, which are very common at Math Stack Exchange.  I have less experience here, but I'm hoping people are more polite here.

Stefan (STack Exchange FAN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a permutation vector `permVec`. Then a permutation matrix should be calculated as follows (modulo some MATLAB syntax bugs, since it's been a while):

```
permMat = function permVecToMat(permVec)
    n = length(permVec);
    permMat = zeros(n,n);
    for i = 1:n
        permMat(i, permVec(i)) = 1
    end
end
```

Then you just take the determinant, and you're done. Consider the code BSD-licensed, even though the Stack Exchange license is CC-BY-SA 3.0 (and I loathe it).

An alternate way of calculating the sign of a permutation would be to convert it into a product of transpositions. If the number of transpositions in such a decomposition is even, the permutation is even; otherwise, the permutation is odd. However, I don't know an algorithm for decomposing a permutation into a product of transpositions.

Comment: Thank you.  Someone at Math Stack Exchange posted the product of transpositions formula.  Whether I use that formula or your code, the Matlab code will be much shorter than the files I saw posted on the Web for this purpose.   I'm not familiar with BSD-licensed code or the Stack Exchange license, and I don't understand how someone would be able to license such a tiny block of code.

Comment: People at StackOverflow found two shorter solutions:                                                   I = speye(length(a));
sign = det(I(:,a));                            and                                                                                                                            y = eye(numel(x));
evenodd = det( y(:,x) );

Comment: @Stefan: Cross-posting is highly frowned upon on the Stack Exchange sites; as a result, this question will be closed. Please don't do this.

Comment: I didn't know this.  I've done it before and no one complained.  You didn't complain when I wrote that my question was part of a question I posted at Math Stack Exchange.  I will do as you request, but can you give me a reason for this?

Comment: I have inquired to Mathematics meta to try find out what the rules and guidelines are regarding cross-posting.  I included the 3-4 line Matlab code I got at Stack Overflow as part of my question at Math Stack Exchange, so now the question has a complete answer at Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Stefan: Posting a question you've asked somewhere else, and for which you have an answer, is considered bad forum etiquette (see the site FAQ). The justification as to why it's bad etiquette is that people feel they've wasted their time if you've posted the question somewhere else and gotten answers. Had I known you already knew how to calculate the sign of a permutation vector efficiently, I wouldn't have bothered to take the time to write my answer.

Comment: the reason you gave for closing the question "closed as not constructive..." is clearly false, or else it would not have received two upvotes and you yourself would not have answered it.  I do not know if the SE system enables you to give the real reason that you closed it. When I posted the question here, I _didn't_ know a good way to find the sign of a permutation vector, or else I wouldn't have asked it.  You showed a good way, and I upvoted, accepted, and complimented your answer.

Comment: @Stefan: The system does not allow me to use "duplicate" as a reason for closing cross-posted questions (because it assumes the duplicate is on the same site). If you didn't post the same question on Stack Overflow, then I misunderstood your comment, and I will reopen the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351039/is-there-a-built-in-function-in-matlab-to-determine-if-a-permutation-is-even-or is the cross-post.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't care if the question is reopened, since I got the answer I watnted.